# Not getting invite acceptation email in ical4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, icalendar, ical4j

I am using the iCal4j for sending the calendar invite. I am able to send the invite to user. But when user accepting the invite I am not getting the revert mail.

```
net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar cal = new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar();
cal.getProperties().add(new ProdId("//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN"));
cal.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
cal.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

System.setProperty(CompatibilityHints.KEY_OUTLOOK_COMPATIBILITY, "true");

java.util.Calendar c1 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
c1.add(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
c1.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, 1);
DateTime start = new DateTime(c1.getTime());
c1.add(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(c1.getTime());

VEvent vEvent = new VEvent();
vEvent.getProperties().add(new DtStart(start));
vEvent.getProperties().add(new DtEnd(end));
vEvent.getProperties().add(Clazz.PUBLIC);

Organizer organizer = new Organizer(URI.create("mailto:mail@gmail.com"));
organizer.getParameters().add(new Cn("mail@gmail.com"));
vEvent.getProperties().add(organizer);

UidGenerator uid = new RandomUidGenerator();
vEvent.getProperties().add(uid.generateUid());


Attendee attendee1 = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:mail@yahoo.com"));
attendee1.getParameters().add(CuType.INDIVIDUAL);
attendee1.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
attendee1.getParameters().add(PartStat.NEEDS_ACTION);
attendee1.getParameters().add(Rsvp.TRUE);
attendee1.getParameters().add(new Cn("mail@yahoo.com"));
vEvent.getProperties().add(attendee1);

vEvent.getProperties().add(new Description("some description");
vEvent.getProperties().add(new Location("location"));
vEvent.getProperties().add(Status.VEVENT_CONFIRMED);
vEvent.getProperties().add(new Summary("Invite summery"));
vEvent.getProperties().add(Transp.OPAQUE);
```

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

When sending calendar invites you need to include directives that tell the client software (e.g. Outlook, etc.) how it should handle the event. This is done via the METHOD property:

http://ical4j.github.io/docs/ical4j/api/3.0.26/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/property/Method.html

Usually you would use either `METHOD:PUBLISH` for events that don't require a response, or `METHOD:REQUEST` where you want accept/decline response.

So if you add `METHOD:REQUEST` property to your invitation you should get a response.

Comment: I have already specified that in my code so I am getting the buttons to accept invite but its not triggering the acceptation mail. I have a also check in the sent items